# Campo Select por Campo Radio - Prestashop

Tags: html, prestashop, smarty

estoy tratando de convertir un campo de tipo Select a un tipo Radio en Prestashop, específicamente en el front, plantilla de productos.

Estoy tratando de convertir el selector de atributos en un selector de tipo radio.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<label for="group_{$id_attribute_group}">{$group.name}</label>
          <div>
          <select
          class="custom-select w-auto"
          id="group_{$id_attribute_group}"
          data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
          name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <option value="{$id_attribute}" title="{$group_attribute.name}"{if $group_attribute.selected} selected="selected"{/if}>{$group_attribute.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
          </div>
```

Y realice la conversión de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox-attribute w-auto">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
            <input 
            class="custom-checkbox"
            type="radio"
            name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]"
            id="{$id_attribute}"
            data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
            {if $group_attribute.selected} checked{/if}
            >
            <label class="label-custom-checkbox" for="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
              {$group_attribute.name}
            </label>
            {/foreach}
          </div>
```

El resultado se muestra en la pantalla, pero me arroja un error.

[image: Error Generado]

Después de eso tiene que poseer CSS, sin embargo por eso no hay problema.
Por favor, si alguien puede decirme estaría genial.

Igualmente, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Jorge, que esta mostrando la consola? Por otra parte puedes activar el debug mode, y mostrarnos el error que te aparece al recargar esa pagina.

Comment: El log no me esta arrojando nada. Solo que es un error en Ajax

Comment: Favor edita tu pregunta, especifica que version de prestashop utilizas y los mensajes del debug mode ON. Sera mas facil para la comunidad ayudarte asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto. El input no poseía el attributo value